# Multiple ping to different sources

Tags: networking, ping

When we do migration, the basic steps is monitoring the loopback ip of various PE to check the health of the migration...

right now using multiple dos windows to pings... it is quite tedious...

Is there better way to ping just from single source? or is there any round robine cmd command...

here is the screenshot.

```
http://lh4.ggpht.com/_QEtUw0y-hBc/S4krGKw6CUI/AAAAAAAAAcs/AZwDhwZelq8/s800/multiple_ping.PNG
```

Thank in Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of these available; any Google search will turn up several. Here's one such freeware utility:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multiple_ping_tool.html

Comment: I've made search too.. may be, my lack of knowledge.. Thx